# How to change the location of the id

Tags: php, location

Source:

```
else if ($key == 'title'){
    if (strlen($value->advObj['title']) > 15)
        $advTitle = substr ($value->advObj['title'], 0,15)."...";
    else
       $advTitle = $value->advObj['title'];
    echo '<a href="index.php?p=newApp&id=&obj=cpn'.$value->advObj['id'].'">'.$value->advObj['id'].' - '.$advTitle.'</a>';
}
```

Result on clicking:

`index.php?p=newApp&id=&obj=cpn1038`

And i need it to be:

`index.php?p=newApp&id=1038&obj=cpn`

How do i do that

Comment: `'<a href="index.php?p=newApp&id='.$value->advObj['id'].'&obj=cpn">'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from it:

```
else if ($key == 'title')
{
    if (strlen($value->advObj['title']) > 15)

        $advTitle = substr ($value->advObj['title'], 0,15)."...";
    else

        $advTitle = $value->advObj['title'];

    echo '<a href="index.php?p=newApp&id='.$value->advObj['id'].'&obj=cpn">'.$advTitle.'</a>';
}
```